# A condition for integrality

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the following problem from Vakil's algebraic geometry notes, 7.2.I.

Suppose $S$ is a subring of $A$ and $r\in A$. Suppose there is a faithful $S[r]$-module $M$ that is finitely generated as an $S$-module.  I'd like to show that $r$ is integral over $S$. The hint given is to "change a few words" in the following proof of Nakayama's Lemma:

[image]

Now, If I take $m_1,...,m_n$ to be generators for $M$ over $S$, and take $I$ to be $S$ as an ideal of $S[r]$, this unfortunately doesn't seem to get me anywhere. What specific alteration of this proof is needed?

Comment: I don't remember the details of how this goes, but the basic idea is to use the characteristic polynomial to produce a monic element of $S[r]$, which thus exhibits $r$ as being integral over $S$.

Comment: Try to replace ${\rm Id}_n$ by $r{\rm Id}_n$. Details can be found in Chapter 5 of Atiyah-Macdonald.